# Why does Ring need to kill Trent?

Tags: daniel-keys-moran, ai-war

I just finished [The A.I. War: Book One](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004XMR5A4). In it there is a short section talking about Ring and says

> Ring wondered if it would be able to kill him [Trent].
>   It desperately needed to.

I'm sure The Long Run talks about this, but it has been a while since I read that. Why did Ring need to kill Trent? Trent doesn't appear to be an enemy of Ring or trying to harm Ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Short Answer

**The AI Ring had a plan to restore the fallen United States to prominence. However, its means and methods left something to be desired. It was reasonably secure in its ability to succeed because from its perspective, no one had any inkling of what it was doing. Except for the AI image, Ralf the Wise and Powerful, who was the image of Trent the Uncatchable, who went from minor 'Net nuisance to true threat in relatively speaking, no time at all. Ring had even aided Trent in the past.**

#### The Long Answer

The text supporting this premise comes from Daniel Keyes Moran's archive website. **All bolded emphasis is mine**:

> Wednesday, April 16, 2008
>
> Interlude: The Crystal Wind
>
> (This follows directly the events in "Trent the Uncatchable and the Temple of 'Toons, available over on kithrup.com.)

~~~~~

> Interlude: The Crystal Wind
>
> Honorable: Having a reputation for keeping one's bargains. Useful for betraying the unwary.
>
> -- Code fragment found in the dictionary of a replicant AI, disassembled in 2091.

[Excerpt: You can read the entire entry here](http://danielkeysmoran.blogspot.com/2008_04_01_archive.html):

> In six decades its existence had never been seriously threatened.
>
> In 2062 it had aided a boy named Trent; had helped him escape a Peaceforcer jail. The possibility that the boy might be of some use in bringing down the Unification was low; a mere quarter of a percent, on the rainy day in 2062 that Ring had helped an eleven year old boy escape from PKF confinement.
>
> Sometimes bets pay off.
>
> Sometimes you're sorry.
>
> **When news of the Elite strike force's assault on Ceres reached the Eldest, it experienced -- to be inaccurate but comprehensible -- a slight flicker of hope. Perhaps the Uncatchable would be caught. Perhaps he would be killed.**
>
> Within six years, if no major parameters were altered, the Unification of Earth would fall -- and not to any human force. The United States would be reborn, would come to control the destiny of the human race.
>
> Under Ring's guidance.
>
> But certain variables caused the Eldest concern. Mohammed Vance, at a low level. Denice Castanaveras, at a somewhat higher one. Several Players worried it -- Kashyapa, Gorgeous George, Big Mac, and the Sons Of FatSam.
>
> **Several AIs also worried Ring -- one named Darkrider in particular, who it suspected was a revenant of Ralf the Wise and Powerful.**
>
> **If the Eldest had been capable of fear, it would have been afraid of Trent. Trent threatened its survival. Ring doubted that anyone in the System except itself, and possibly Darkrider, had made note of the nano-assemblers being shipped to the Belt, of the processors and RTS RAM being purchased by companies affiliated with Trent the Uncatchable; the purchases Ring had tracked were bought in a thousand small quantities over the space of almost two years, and shipped to the Belt a piece at a time. And Ring was certain that there were purchases it had not tracked.**
>
> Ring knew there was one AI in the System smarter and faster than itself: Trent. It knew that there was no simulation it had run, that Trent had not.

Comment: That was more or less what I assumed. I wasn't sure if Ring had any reason to believe Trent was against the US rising back to prominence.

Comment: I don't think Trent even cared about US prominence all that much, but his inherent curiosity could have made him a threat to Ring, should their two paths intersect. Ring just wanted to stack the deck completely in its favor if it could.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Ring's simulations showed that the PKF was going to lose global dominance in a few years if there was no interference from Trent.  Ring could then bring the USA back as the leader of the pack.  After the Temple of Toons, Ring knew that Trent was going to get involved with the PKF again, thus losing the chances of bringing the United States back to power.  Ring wants to kill Trent so that the PKF does not stay in power (according to its calculations).

Answer (score 0):

You overlook this simple answer that is brought up in "*The Last Dancer*".

After Ring attempts to coerce Denice into undertaking a task to evaluate Sedon for him by threatening to reveal her identity to the world. In return, Denice comments to Ring that if he betrays her and Trent finds out about it that he (Trent) will come after Ring and will not stop until Ring is dead. Needless to say, Ring does betray her.
It is reasonable to assume that later in the story, during the Tricentennial Revolution, when Trent sends his Image to Denice during the battle for the satellites she would have filled Trent in on what Ring has been doing, including declaring war on her and Ralf the Wise and Powerful, Trent's old image, who is now an AI himself.
Understanding this motivation requires that you have read both "*The Long Run*" and "*The Last Dancer*", the prior two books in this series.

Comment: The wording of your answer seems a little unclear. Can you edit it?